# Number next to frame title in beamer

Tags: beamer, enumerate, frame-title

I would like to use the enumerate circles and format and enumerate some beamer titles. I.e. for a handful of slides, I would like the titles to show up as:

[image]

where I could freely tweak the number inside the blue circle.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\numcirc}[1]{%
%   \usebeamerfont*{item projected}%
    \large
  \usebeamercolor[bg]{item projected}%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{0ex}{1ex}{2ex}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0pt}{.75ex}}{1.2ex}
    \pgfusepath{fill}
    \pgftext[base]{\color{fg}#1}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
  \usebeamerfont*{frametitle}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\numcirc{5} test}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]